# Repeated bitwise shift

Tags: c

I have some code which extracts bits from a number:

```
uint32_t foo = getValue(); /*this just returns a value for `foo`*/

while (foo){
    foo <<= 2;
    doSomethingWithFoo(foo);
}
```

I'm worried that I have undefined behaviour here since I'll end up "overshifting" `foo`. Am I correct?

Comment: It could happen if your machine has a larger `unsigned int` than `uint32_t`. Then `foo` is promoted to this larger `int` type, so is the result. When you try to assign this result back to `foo` but if it won't fit into the range of `uint32_t`, it's UB.

Comment: @user3528438 "assign this result back to foo but if it won't fit into the range of uint32_t, it's UB."  --> Disagree.  Assignment to an unsigned has well defined behavior when the value is outside the unsigned variable range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is safe.

That's because the behaviour of several shifts is well-defined (so long as each one doesn't shift by too much). Essentially, you're starting with a brand new `foo` on each iteration.

The problems only arise if you attempt to shift by more bits than there are in the type **in one go**.

Comment: I have marked +1, but even `(foo<<24)<<24` is safe (if somewhat pointless)

Comment: what about a comma operator foo << 24, foo << 24?

Comment: @P45Imminent that would be safe, but would produce the same answer twice, and discard the first one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no undefined behavior as how bit-shifts work with shifting data is very defined. You can think of the bit shift as a window.For example below in an 8 bit value you could have:

```
b7  b6  b5  b4  b3  b2  b1  b0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
```

The value above is 0x99 in hex. If we were to bit shift left 1, we would end up with this:

```
b7  b6  b5  b4  b3  b2  b1  b0
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
```

Which would be 0x32. If we were to bit-shift right one we would just get this:

```
b7  b6  b5  b4  b3  b2  b1  b0
0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
```

Which would be 0x4C. Even in extreme cases where we are shifting over the number of bits we have which in this case would be 8, anything outsize the window is 0 so we know we would end up with 0x00 as shown below.

```
b7  b6  b5  b4  b3  b2  b1  b0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

So every scenario possible is defined by this operation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use circular left or right bitwise shift functions.

```
uint8_t circularLeftShift(uint8_t var, uint8_t numOfBits) {

    if (numOfBits < 1 || numOfBits>7) return var;

     uint8_t msb = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < numOfBits; i++)
    {
    msb = var & 128;
    msb = msb >> 7;
    var = var << 1;
    var = var | msb;
    }
    return var; 
}



uint8_t circularRightShift(uint8_t var, uint8_t numOfBits) {

    if (numOfBits < 1 || numOfBits>7) return var;

    uint8_t lsb = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfBits; i++)
    {
        lsb = var & 1;
        lsb = lsb << 7;
        var = var >> 1;
        var = var | lsb;
    }
    return var;
}
```